# How to remove url and date text from web page print?

Tags: jquery, printing, html

I'm using a Jquery to print the webpage (A div portion of it). It's working fine, But it also prints the Web Page Name, URL, Page Number and Date at page header and footer. How to remove these things from printable area?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css code snippet

```
<style type="text\css" media="print">
  #myFooter, #myHeader
  {
    display: none;
  }
```

This may also help you with your problem: [Printing without header and footer](http://javascript.bigresource.com/Printing-without-header-and-footer--y9mCNznMr.html)

Comment: And where to add this IDs 'myFooter' and 'myHeader'

Comment: I think these should be default tags and you don't need to set them manually. But I have to check this first. What happens when you print your page?

Comment: You may need to format your webpage with css to overwrite the header and footer. I found this [post](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-11003.html), maybe you can set the content height and width to 100%?

Comment: I'm still getting that Header and Footer

Comment: Maybe you should try another way. If it's impossible to remove the header/footer, you can create a print friendly page like wikipedia does?